# Regular expression for attribute value

Tags: java, regex, jmeter

I want to create a regular expression for getting the `jti` value from the following string in my JMeter script.

The `jti` value in the below string is `a1e94dba-e38e-4ae2-b9c5-1b1e58045bdb`

`GET https://tdc-eng-wrt-reactwebet.run.asv-dr.ice.test.io/#token_type=bearer&access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.gySof9eiQNBNDhBSxgFaRHlXmQM9_Aj-AaA7yv5RarY8O5IRGKXZfZbIi0TmuGFzBAHtYFJgl9HixYiWoOQdob5hA6iHx6q4epJzh82Un_OqlmiwVNYzo36Cb65YsLHTPysA46qRDlmzS_GDKduV1G2d5iIduq0J6nJ_ctEVr1XE32wonS-gACjSSZSKpQNFLZqkKk10rV9Pr-h3ILdh0IkDM30Yinou8OJxgx6m2JTPH6BmeuMNygH4_DpVRtAR6iYc4ex2RgAa4o2KZd17rQxYHyk7tIKYg5C1580zSTSOBFjyNTnhzZvKbK11UMFCGEwU1Jxm39WW9Ijg0O8Whg&state=&expires_in=43199&scope=openid&jti=a1e94dba-e38e-4ae2-b9c5-1b1e58045bdb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regular expression will be `jti=(.*)` but don't forget to click on `URL` radio button as it seems the provided string is available in URL of HTTP request. Please refer below snapshot
[image]

Comment: @user6061548 is your issue resolved or still facing some challenges